# What's wrong with following jelly script template for cppcheck in email-ext plugin of hudson

Tags: hudson, jelly, cppcheck, email-ext

What's wrong with following jelly script template for cppcheck in email-ext plugin of hudson.

```
<!-- CppCheck TEMPLATE -->
<!--<j:set var="cppClassName" value="CppcheckBuildAction" />-->
<j:set var="cppcheckAction" value="${it.getAction('com.thalesgroup.hudson.plugins.cppcheck.CppcheckBuildAction')}" />
<TABLE width="100%">
    <TR><TD class="bg1" colspan="2"><B>CppCheck Result</B></TD></TR>
         <TR bgcolor="white"><TD class="test_failed" colspan="2"><B><li>Failed: ${cppcheckResult.summary} </li></B></TD></TR>
</TABLE>
<j:if test="${cppcheckAction!=null}">
  <j:set var="cppcheckResult" value="${cppcheckAction.result}" />
  <j:if test="${cppcheckResult!=null}">
  <TABLE width="100%">
    <TR><TD class="bg1" colspan="2"><B>CppCheck Result</B></TD></TR>
         <TR bgcolor="white"><TD class="test_failed" colspan="2"><B><li>Failed: ${cppcheckResult.getSummary} </li></B></TD></TR>
  </TABLE>
  </j:if>
<BR/>
</j:if>
```

Comment: Can you please give some more information, like what error do you get?

Comment: @Toon, crystal ball says cppCheckAction is null.  See [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13888338/sending-cppcheck-result-report-on-email-from-jenkins-using-email-ext-plugin)